# switching fragment from a gridview adapter

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I have a code structure like following

```
1.MAINACTIVITY
2.FRAGMENTACTIVITY
3.GRIDVIEWADAPTER

-In my main activity I have set code to display and switch fragments that I have in my project
-In fragment activity I have set a custom gridview with a image and text layout
-In gridview adapter I have onitemclicklistener for gridview items
```

Now I would like to switch the fragments on the click of onitemclicklistener of gridview,
but my code to switch fragments is within the main activity. How can pass the parameters need to switch the fragment to main activity from the grid view adapter class.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {
    GridView gridview;
    FragmentActivity frag_activity;

    public MainActivity () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.frag_activity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_form,
                container, false);
        gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        GridMaker();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        GridMaker();

    }

    private void GridMaker() {
        gridview.setAdapter(new Custom_Adapter(frag_activity));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                String name = null;

                if (arg2 == 0) {
                    name = "A";
                    displayView(arg2, name);
                } else if (arg2 == 1) {
                    name = "B";
                    displayView(arg2, name);
                } else if (arg2 == 2) {
                    name = "C";
                    displayView(arg2, name);
                } else if (arg2 == 3) {
                    name = "D";
                    displayView(arg2, name);
                } else if (arg2 == 4) {
                    name = "E";
                    displayView(arg2, name);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void displayView(int position, String name) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new DynamicFragment(name);

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    }

}
```